# how to set up msxml language?

Tags: windows, locale, msxml, msxml6

I installed english windows server 2008 r2. MSXml 6.0 was installed as part of os. When i check some xml documents, i see english error messages. For example:

```
E­l­e­m­e­nt 'Ра­зде­л1Ра­сче­тПо­На­чи­сле­нны­мУ­пла­че­нны­м2014' is u­n­e­x­p­e­c­t­ed a­c­c­o­r­d­i­ng to c­o­n­t­e­nt m­o­d­el of p­a­r­e­nt e­l­e­m­e­nt 'РА­СЧЕ­Т_­ПО­_­СТРА­ХО­ВЫ­М_­ВЗНО­СА­М_­НА­_­О­ПС_­И­_­О­МС_­ПЛА­ТЕ­ЛЬ­ЩИ­КА­МИ­_­ПРО­И­ЗВО­ДЯ­ЩИ­МИ­_­ВЫ­ПЛА­ТЫ­_­ФЛ_­2015'. E­x­p­e­c­t­i­n­g: Ко­ли­че­ство­Стра­ни­ц.
```

I want to get errors in russian. I tried following:

1. Set up russian locale and display language in os
2. Replace current msxml6.dll with dll from preinstalled russian windows mashine
3. Reinstall Msxml from microsoft site, choosing russian language

I see in ProcessMonitor that msxml keep on loading

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US\msxml6r.dll.mui

localization file, but can't find out where it stores this information

P.S. On preinstalled russian windows no such problem occurs

Comment: Have you tried installing the Language Packs for the languages you need?  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1246

Comment: Hello. Yes, i have installed russian language pack